# Applying a column filter only for a specific column

Tags: tableau-api

I apply a color filter for one of my column `P / W` so that the color of cells change based on this column's value.

[image]

But as you see in the picture, all other columns change color with it how can I apply the color filter only on `P / W`?

Comment: What are the pills in your rows and columns?  [Measure Values]?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional colors apply to green pills, regarded as measures. Remove everything but P/W from your measures in the marks box, and instead add them to the rows shelf as discrete (right-click, select discrete). Then they will not be colored.